# Server not reachable due to port mapping?

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, webserver

I have a server and a notebook at home which I both use for two different ubuntu server. Because there are two and I want to communicate with both, I need to do port mapping. I do this for SSH and for one server also for HTTP/HTTPS and MySQL.
This looks like that:

```
| IP address      | Local Port | External Port | Protocol | Device   |
|-----------------|------------|---------------|----------|----------|
| 192.168.0.165   | 22         | 22165         | TCP      | Server   |    <- SSH
| 192.168.0.165   | 8165       | 80            | TCP      | Server   |    <- HTTP
| 192.168.0.165   | 43165      | 443           | TCP      | Server   |    <- HTTPS
| 192.168.0.165   | 3306       | 36165         | TCP      | Server   |    <- MySQL
| 192.168.0.179   | 22         | 22179         | TCP      | Notebook |    <- SSH
```

Now, connecting to my server via SSH and port `22165` works fine. But when I try to reach my website, which I host on the same server with nginx, with the public IP or domain, it can't reach it. It also can't reach the MySQL database even when I type `36165` as the port. Pinging my server from an external server works.

```
user@externalserver:~$ ping my.public.ip
PING my.public.ip (my.public.ip) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from my.public.ip: icmp_seq=1 ttl=44 time=107 ms
64 bytes from my.public.ip: icmp_seq=2 ttl=44 time=100 ms
64 bytes from my.public.ip: icmp_seq=3 ttl=44 time=111 ms
^C
--- my.public.ip ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
```

Yesterday I finished setting up OpenVPN on the same server. Since then it doesn't work anymore. But I already stopped the OpenVPN service with `systemctl stop` but it still didn't work. And I don't think it's because OpenVPN. But it's also weird if it's because of the port mapping, because I tested it after I did the port mapping and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I could fix the issue. It was the ubuntu firewall `ufw` which was enabled after setting up openvpn and which didn't allowed port 80, 443 and 3306.